# Ubuntu 14.04 wired connection not working

Tags: networking, 14.04, customization, wired

I'm brand new to Linux so I thought I'd give it a shot for my gaming pc I just built, however it says the wired connection is not connected.

When it is I really can't give out the terminal info Because it won't connect however when I ping my IP address in terminal it says unreachable and I’ve  tried a couple of other things so yeah can someone please help.

I'm just debating on getting a wireless card but I'm not sure I'll have the same problems so if you can help thanks.

**Edit fixes code tags**

```
sudo lshw -c network
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product :rtl8111/8168/8411 pci express gigabit Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek semiconductor co.,ltd.
physical id 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 06
serial 74:d4:35:5a:67:98 size 10mbits/s
capacity: 1gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock:33mhz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list Ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 1000bt 10000bt-fd autonegotiation n=2.3lk-napi duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no muliticast=yes port=MMI speed 10mbit/s
resources: irq:42 ioport=e100 Ioport=e100 (size 256) memory:fea000000-fea00fff memory:d0000000-d0003ff



ifconfig -a 
Eth0
Link encap: ether net hwaddr 74:d4:35:5a:67:98
Up broadcast multicast mtu:1500 metric:1 
Rx packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
Tx packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
Rx bytes:0 (0.0 B) tx bytes:858 (858.0 B) 
Lo 
link encap:local loopback
Inet addr:127.0.0.1 mask:255.0.0.0.
Inet6 addr: ::1/128 scope:host
Up loopback running mtu:65536 metric:1 
Rx packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
Tx packets:32 errors:9 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
Rx bytes:2432 (2.4 Kb)tx bytes:2432 )2.4 kb)


for netstat -rn
Kernel ip routing table
Destination   Gateway genmask flags mss windows irtt iface
For having the sudo dhclient -r then dhclient then the config showed
Eth0 
Link encap:Ethernet hwaddr 74:d4::35:5a:67:98
Up broadcast multi cast mtu:1500 metric:1 
Rx packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
Tx packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
Rx bytes:0 (0.0 B) tx bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo
Link encap: local loopback
Inet addr:127.0.0.1 mask:255.0.0.0
Inet6 addr: ::1/128 scope:host
Up loopback running mtu:65536 metric:1
Rx packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
Tx packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
Rx Bytes:9505 (9.5 kb) tx bytes:9505 (9.5 Kb)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to waste your time @meccooll it was the cable I swapped it and now it is working

Comment: Well that was a good exercise to troubleshoot it down to hardware. Feel free to accept bellow answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not hearing anything on the link (not receiving any packets) troubleshoot hardware, cables, router, network card...