# WIFI working but Wired Connection not working: Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I have successful connection through **WIFI in both Ubuntu and Windows**.

(`I have dual boot:Ubuntu 14.04 installed & upgraded to 14.04.1 and Windows 8.1`)

But I have **problem in wired connection in Ubuntu only**(though it works fine in Windows).

I have consulted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485707/ubuntu-14-04-wired-connection-not-working) but no luck. I think I have some problem in **setting IP address statically** from Ubuntu side. The connection is shown but I cannot access the Internet and even not gateway (I mean `192.168.1.1`).

I followed the way described [here](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/):

So my **NetworkManager.conf** looks like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

But I **removed other part** that were by default.

And my **interface** is like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.102 #I have seen from Windows that it's 1.102
gateway 192.168.1.1 # 1.1 is because I use 192.168.1.1 to access router settings
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

And I used following to restart new settings

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

**Now I have**

**ifconfig -a**

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:4b:e1:a2:2f:fa  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9a4b:e1ff:fea2:2ffa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:77228 (77.2 KB)  TX bytes:72394 (72.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1240162 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1240162 (1.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:2a:82:fa:e9:f8  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1085963 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:348905 (348.9 KB)
```

**route -n**

```
 Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

**ping -c3 192.168.1.1**

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
pipe 2
```

**ping -c3 4.2.2.2**

```
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
pipe 3
```

**And after following the link I have new settings (Previous was AutoEthernet and new one I got is ifeth(up). I guess I should try connecting the ifeth0(up)).**

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: After doing all these steps, what exactly is the problem? Do you get a static IP but can't access the internet? Or do you not get a static IP? What's the output of `ifconfig -a; route -n; ping -c3 192.168.1.1; ping -c3 4.2.2.2` after doing all the steps in your question? Also, question: do you actually have these end of line comments in your `interfaces` file (like `address 192.168.1.102 #this comment`)? All comments in this file have to be in a separate line, not at the end of a line.

Comment: @AlaaAli Sorry for unclear question. Please see my edited question. Thank you

Comment: @AlaaAli Sorry for my late response, as I need to switch OS to Windows to use AskUbuntu and See what I have by using Ubuntu. :-)

Comment: @AlaaAli I don't have comments, just for the question here

Comment: Your `eth0` has an IP of `192.168.0.102` (from your `ifconfig` output). Did you previously set a static IP? Or is that being automatically assigned from a DHCP? Are you sure your Windows uses `1.102` not `0.102`? Try executing the command `sudo ifdown eth0` then `sudo ifup eth0` and check the `ifconfig` output again.

Comment: Yes it's 1.102. Please see here http://themomotrail.orgfree.com/Untitled.png

Comment: @AlaaAli should changing eth0 ip to 192.168.1.102 be fruitful?

Comment: @AlaaAli A couple of days earlier I was trying to use entrydns.net if that matters

Comment: No, entrydns won't matter. Okay, here's what you should do: change `managed=true` to `managed=false` in `NetworkManager.conf`, then `service network-manager restart`, then `service networking restart`. Verify `eth0` has a `1.102` IP from `ifconfig`. If that doesn't work, delete all the eth0 "connections" in the Network Manager settings (networking icon top right > Edit connections) and restart the services again. God I hate NetworkManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16929/discussion-between-alaa-ali-and-nabin).

Comment: Problem solved finally. Should i post what I have done?

Comment: Yes, and mark it as the accepted answer when you can. But if the solution was found in another answer here in Ask Ubuntu, flag your question to be closed as a duplicate.